# Do users that access TFS Web but not Visual Studio count towards TFS licenses?

Tags: licensing

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I do see other licensing questions here, not to mentiona  "licensing" tag.

Our team consists of 10 people.  Only 2 are developers.  The other 8 are technical, but do not need to write code.  We want everyone to track tasks in the same place.  The task management integration in TFS is very handy.  If we only have say 5 CAL's for TFS, can all 10 of us log into TFS web?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the stakeholder license. It's already available for Visual Studio Online and will be also included in the Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 4 (which hasn't been released yet). This license is free and it allows stakeholders to organize backlog, create and modify workitems, create and modify queries.

You can read more about stakeholder license: [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work-as-a-stakeholder-vs.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/07/09/upcoming-vs-online-licensing-changes.aspx)